# I want to make something like this for my android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I want to make a temperature increasing and decreasing thing, with **+** and **-** buttons as shown in the image, but I am finding anything on the internet.

[image]

Comment: That's going to be a custom view you'll need to draw yourself using Canvas,.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the existing codebase like [simple-gauge-android](https://github.com/Gruzer/simple-gauge-android)